# How can I trigger an insert to a google sheet when receiving to gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets

I have a google form that redirects to PayPal upon submission and I store all the submission data into the response sheet. I want to be able to store data in the same sheet indicating whether or not they actually followed through with payment on PayPal.

When they pay, PayPal sends me an email. Is there a way to add a row to a google sheet upon the arrival the PayPal email?

Example:

> 1. User submits data through my Google form
> 2. Form data is added to response sheet
> 3. User complete PayPal payment
> 4. PayPal sends confirmation email to gmail account
> 5. *[what I want]:* Logic is triggered (or run every X minutes) that notices the email based on the PayPal subject line or whatever and inserts a row into the google sheet.

Comment: Yes, with [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) and [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), have you coded anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IFTTT (free, basic functionality): https://ifttt.com/

Zapier (freemium, loads of functionality/integrations): https://zapier.com/

Answer (score 1):

The most logical way I can think this is possible involves two steps:

1. Set up a filter on Gmail so that you can group those messages with a label.
2. Using scripts, do something like this:

### Code:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("PayPal").getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    if (threads[i].isUnread()) {
      // write code to add to Spreadsheet
      threads[i].markRead();
    }
```

You'll have to set this on a timer that'll go off every hour or 30 minutes.  You don't want it going off every minute because I think Google restricts that.

Comment: Not quite sure why, but it doesn't seem to let me type as Code (using 4 spaces)... I tried for like 10 minutes.

Comment: If code is immediately following a list, without text in between, something goes wrong with the code formatting.